# Centering input buttons inside a table

Tags: html, css

So the table is centered perfectly. However the td tags aren't correctly. I want the input button to all be centered without any space in between. I have td align center but nothing seems to be working.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>BuyRite Liquor Store - English Town Road (Old Bridge, NJ)</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>

 <table align ="center">  
  
 <form> 
  
  <tr width = "100%">
   <td align="center"><input type="text" id = "input" name = "dbname" placeholder="Database Name"></td>
   <td align="center"><input type="text" id = "input" name = "tblname" placeholder="Table Name"></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td align="center"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="createDB" value="Create Database"></td> 
   <td align="center"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="deleteDB" value="Delete Database"></td>
  </tr>   
  
  <tr>
   <td align="center" width="1px"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="createTBL" value="Create Table"></td> 
   <td align="center" width="1px"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="emptyTBL" value="Empty Table"></td> 
   <td align="center" width="1px"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="deleteTBL" value="Delete Table"></td> 
  </tr>
 
 </table>
 </form>
 
 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: The `<input>` elements are perfectly centred within their parent `<td>` elements. The elements you wish to have positioned next to each other would need to be within the same cell.

Comment: And don't duplicate IDs. They **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are centered in your `<td>` tags. If you put all the buttons you would like into one td, they will all be centered.

[See the JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/merugijida/1/edit)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BuyRite Liquor Store - English Town Road (Old Bridge, NJ)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form> 
      <table align="center">   
        <tr width="100%">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="text" id="input" name="dbname" placeholder="Database Name">
            <input type="text" id="input" name="tblname" placeholder="Table Name">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <input class="btnCreateDB" type="submit" name="createDB" value="Create Database">
            <input class="btnDeleteDB" type="submit" name="deleteDB" value="Delete Database">
          </td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
          <td align="center" width="1px">
            <input class="btnCreateTable" type="submit" name="createTBL" value="Create Table">
            <input class="btnEmptyTable" type="submit" name="emptyTBL" value="Empty Table">
            <input class="btnDeleteTable" type="submit" name="deleteTBL" value="Delete Table">
          </td> 
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question the input elements are given a default padding by the browser - In chrome this is 1px, and a border, in chrome this is also around the 1px mark.

To remove the border I've added in a `<style>` element that explicitly specifies that any `<input>`'s which are children of `<td>` elements will have padding of 0px. I gave the two inputs you are referring to a class of `.input` so that the styles don't get applied elsewhere.

See the JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cmmvn9dd/1/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BuyRite Liquor Store - English Town Road (Old Bridge, NJ)</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

td input {
  padding:0px;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>

  <table align ="center">       

  <form> 

    <tr width = "100%">
      <td align="center"><input type="text" class="input" name = "dbname" placeholder="Database Name"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="text"  class="input" name = "tblname" placeholder="Table Name"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="createDB" value="Create Database"></td>   
      <td align="center"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="deleteDB" value="Delete Database"></td>
    </tr>           

    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="1px"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="createTBL" value="Create Table"></td> 
      <td align="center" width="1px"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="emptyTBL" value="Empty Table"></td> 
      <td align="center" width="1px"><input class= "button2-link" type="submit" name="deleteTBL" value="Delete Table"></td> 
    </tr>

  </table>
  </form>



</body>  
</html>
```